# Yii2 Read saved data in custom template form field

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I created a template for a form field (`yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm`).

**_form.php**

```
<?php
echo $form->field($model, 'test_radio', [
    'template' =>
    '<div id="user-test_radio" value="" >                                    
                            <p style="margin:0"><label>TYPE</label></p>
                            <p style="margin:0"><label><input type="radio" name="user[test_radio]" value="PF" checked=""/> PF </label></p>
                            <p ><label><input type="radio" name="user[test_radio]" value="PJ" checked=""/> PJ </label></p>
                        </div>'
])?>
```

It is working fine and save the data on database.

But when I try to update, the values is not loaded. The radiobox is not checked.

How can I create a template and read the saved data from database?

Controller actions:

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new User();

    if( $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save() ){
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Updates an existing User model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return mixed
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if( $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save() ){
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

This is the HTML I am trying to reproduce:

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-12">
  <legend>Demo</legend>


  <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">

        <p>
        </p>
        <div class="form-group field-provider-demo_type">
          <div id="provider-demo_type" value="">
            <p style="margin:0"><label>TYPE</label></p>
            <p style="margin:0"><label><input type="radio" name="Provider[demo_type]" value="PF" checked=""> PF </label></p>
            <p><label><input type="radio" name="Provider[demo_type]" value="PJ" checked=""> PJ </label></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p></p>

        <p>
        </p>
        <div class="form-group field-provider-demo_default">
          <div id="provider-demo_default">
            <p style="margin:0"><label>DEFAULT</label></p>
            <p style="margin:0"><label><input type="radio" name="Provider[demo_default]" value="Acme" checked=""> Acme </label></p>
            <p><label><input type="radio" name="Provider[demo_default]" value="Custom" checked=""> Custom </label></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p></p>


      </div>



      <div class="col-md-6 ">

        <p>


        </p>
        <div>
          <p style="margin:0"><label><input type="radio" name="Provider[demo]" value="Own"> Own</label></p>
          <p><label><input type="radio" name="Provider[demo]" value="Service (freela)"> Service (freela)</label></p>
        </div>


        <p></p>

        <p>


        </p>
        <div>
          <p style="margin:0"><label>ASSIGNMENT</label></p>
          <p style="margin:0"><label><input type="radio" name="Provider[demo_assignment]" value="Total"> Total</label></p>
          <p style="margin:0"><label><input type="radio" name="Provider[demo_assignment]" value="Partial"> Partial</label></p>
          <p style="margin:0"><label><input type="radio" name="Provider[demo_assignment]" value="Open source"> Open source</label></p>
        </div>
        <p></p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>





  <p></p>

</div>
```

[image: Something like this img]

---

**EDIT**

Below you can find the actual html content inside the `template` optino that i am trying to transform in Yii

```
<?php
echo $form->field($model, 'test_radio', [
    'template' =>
    '<div id="job-category" >                                    
        <h2>Category</h2>
          <input type="radio" name="Job[category]" value="male"> Freelancer<br>
          <p><label>Art</label></p>
          <input type="radio" name="Job[category]" value="Diagrammer"> Diagrammer<br>
          <input type="radio" name="Job[category]" value="Illustrator"> Illustrator<br>
          <input type="radio" name="Job[category]" value="Cartographer"> Cartographer<br>
          <p><label>ICO</label></p>
          <input type="radio" name="Job[category]" value="Photographer"> Photographer<br>
          <input type="radio" name="Job[category]" value="Cartoonist"> Cartoonist<br>

          <p><label>TEXT</label></p>
          <input type="radio" name="Job[category]" value="Author"> Author<br>

          <p><label>LOT</label></p>
          <input type="radio" name="Job[category]" value="Image Bank"> Image Bank<br>
          <input type="radio" name="Job[category]" value="Literary Agency"> Literary Agency<br>
          <input type="radio" name="Job[category]" value="News Agency"> News Agency<br>

    </div>'
])?>
```

Comment: update your question and  add  . you  related control/action and view code  ..

Comment: It is the default controller action generated by gii. I will add anyway

Comment: Your template makes `field()` output completely static, you might as well skip `$form->field()` call and use HTML directly.

Comment: Did you tried to use [`radio()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#radio()-detail)?

Comment: the html you added is not the actual html that you need to transform using `ActiveForm` but the output of your current `ActiveForm`. and there is no point of `value` attribute for the `div`, please provide the original html if you have one or you must explain why you are adding the wrapper div inside the `.form-control` and assigning the `id`, do you actually need it ?

Comment: are you looking to make something like this https://imgur.com/a/IvAXKVu

Comment: Yeah but when I go to update page it do not load the values. When you use a template are there a way to load the values?

Comment: you should never remove the original content of your question against which any answer is posted as your current content is making my answer irrelevant, you should always add an **EDIT** heading and add the new information under that heading, currently i have reverted it and added the new content. Secondly the `HTML` you provided has sub headings inside the `job_title` section , where are you retrieving the information from, i mean i can say it would be from database but in which format are you getting the dta for the `job_title`add the array that you are or want to supply to the radio list.

Comment: Ok sorry. This information is fixed, it is not from database.

Comment: do you mean to say that the options for the `job_category(Freelancer, Diagrammer, Illustrator, Cartographer)`  are not saved in the database and you are providing them statically?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no actual `HTML` that you are following but a specific layout that you have mentioned in the question via the image, you can still achieve it using the `ActiveForm` `$form->field()->radioList()` method and the `template` option.

You can generate something like below which matches your given layout

[image]

```
echo $form->field($model, 'type', [
    'template' =>'{label}<br/>{input}{error}'
])->radioList(['PF'=> 'PF', 'PJ' => 'PJ'],['tag'=>'div','separator'=>'<br/>']);

echo $form->field($model, 'default', [
    'template' =>'{label}<br/>{input}{error}'
])->radioList(['Acme'=> 'Acme', 'Custom' => "Custom",'Own'=>'Own'],['tag'=>'div','separator'=>'<br/>']);
```

The above will generate the `HTML` like below

```
<div class="form-group field-provider-type required">
  <label class="control-label">Type</label><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="Provider[type]" value="">
  <div id="provider-type" aria-required="true">
    <label><input type="radio" name="Provider[type]" value="PF" checked=""> PF</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Provider[type]" value="PJ"> PJ</label>
  </div>
  <div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. I updated my question with the real code I am trying to do.